# Ubuntu 12.04 how to get tsclient back?

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop

I "upgraded" to Ubuntu 12.04 over the weekend. `tsclient` (terminal server client), which I used to use all the time here at work, is gone.
It was replaced by `Remmina`, which is terribly unstable and buggy.

Does anyone know how to get `tsclient` installed on Ubuntu 12.04?  How do I get `tsclient` back?

Comment: start to use remmmina. It's part od 12.04 and much better than old tsclient.

Comment: I have been using remmina and it is not much better. It crashes, the clipboard doesn't work, the num lock key is backward and the shortcut keys are screwy. tsclient may be old, but it worked great!

Comment: Drake, how do I get rid of Unity and get back to a desktop that works?

Comment: Have you tried vinagre? It now supports Windows RDP. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Vinagre

Comment: Also, after you install gnome-panel on 12.04 you'll have the option to log into gnome and gnome classic

Comment: -1 the internet is full of "unity sucks and i am unable to do anything" threads, thus no research effort. It distracts from the real question, too.

Comment: duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/131042/how-do-i-get-tsclient-back-in-12-04

Answer (score 3):

You can try [grdesktop](http://www.nongnu.org/grdesktop/). It is also a GNOME frontend to rdesktop.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way that I could think of to install tsclient is to download the package meant for previous release and installing it manually. But, be warned that it could break your apt and create dependencies problems among others.

Anyway, download the tsclient package and the relevant dependencies from [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/tsclient).

For a typical 64-bit architecture, the following command would install tsclient for you:

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -i tsclient_0.150-4ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

For 32-bit system:

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -i tsclient_0.150-4ubuntu2_i386.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

## Install `tsclient` in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

The best client to use rdesktop is `tsclient`. No doubt!

`Remmina` is terrible (buggy)!

`grdesktop` works, but does not have the same features as `tsclient` (share your folders automatically on the remote computer, for example) and his aesthetic is horrible.

Due to the long time without updates `tsclient` is increasingly difficult to be installed on Ubuntu.

But the good news is that `tsclient` works perfectly in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS! To make it work without being bothered by the Ubuntu package manager do what I explain here.

Download the package `tsclient` (0150) for the desired architecture (64 or 32 bit) from http://pkgs.org/

---

Install the package using `--force-all` to ignore dependencies.

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -i tsclient_0.150-4ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

This package will be installed with the status "broken". If this situation continues the `tsclient` will be removed in the first update or update will not work or `Ubuntu Software Center` will not work.

The actions to repair `Ubuntu Software Center` suggested by Ubuntu also remove `tsclient`

---

To change the broken status of `tsclient` do the following...

Source: http://www.sudo-juice.com/ignore-broken-packages-ubuntu-aptitude/

"IGNORE BROKEN PACKAGES IN UBUNTU (OR ANY SYSTEM WITH APTITUDE PACKAGE MANAGER)

Ignoring broken packages in Ubuntu or any other distribution of Linux using Aptitude package manager would usually be a bad thing and it’s not recommended. Maintaining a system of broken packages kind of defeats the object.

BUT, I recently came across a situation where I had to install a 32bit version of Chrome on my 64bit Ubuntu. I did this by completely removing previous versions of Chrome, then downloading the .deb file from the Chrome download page and installing it from command line using….

```
sudo dpkg --force-architecture -i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
```

This worked.

So why the need to ignore broken packages?

Well though it worked, it left some dependency issues. The dependencies are installed, but because they are working in a sort of compatibility mode (MultiArch) they show as broken dependencies. This forces Synaptic to display it as broken package every time you try to update, not only display it as broken but prevent you from updating until you fix it. Synaptic's fix is to completely remove it.

Ok then, How do I force Synaptic to ignore the ‘broken’ package?

Firstly you have to find the dependencies that are causing the errors:

Open Synaptic Package Manager (you may need to install this first “sudo apt-get install synaptic“)
Find the ‘broken’ package, you will probably be notified there is broken package – click the link to Broken from the list on the left of the screen – make a note of the package name
Right click on the package, select Properties
Go to the Dependencies tab, make a note of the dependencies listed in italics
Leave Synaptic open to test the fix later
Now we need to edit a file. Open a terminal and type/copy:

```
sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

This should open the file status (which can be pretty long), you now have to find the package name (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> should help). There should be a little section for it that resembles this:

```
Package: google-chrome-stable
Status: install ok unpacked
Priority: optional
Section: web
Installed-Size: 119100
Maintainer: Chrome Linux Team <chromium-dev@chromium.org>
Architecture: i386
Version: 22.0.1229.94-r161065
Config-Version: 20.0.1132.57-r145807
Replaces: google-chrome
Provides: google-chrome, www-browser
Depends: libasound2 (>> 1.0.22), {...and many others!...}, libcurl3, wget
Description: The web browser from Google
```

Now delete the dependencies (the italic ones you noted earlier) from the Depends line, save the file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>) and close.

**Editor note**

```
In our case just remove the "libpanel-applet2-0 (>= 2.26.0)"
```

How do I know if my "broken" packages are being ignored?

Now click Reload in Synaptic. You shouldn’t receive the broken dependency message you did earlier.

Issues?

The only problem I ran into with ignoring broken packages were updates. I had to update chrome which involved doing this again (because I had to completely remove it in the first place!).

Like I said before, I don’t condone ignoring broken packages, or anything broken for that matter! Sometimes these things have to be done though.

---

To prevent `tsclient` to be removed in future updates do the following...

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package

Install synaptic using `sudo apt-get install synaptic`.

Run using `gksudo synaptic` and on the search box locate the package you want to lock, ie: `gedit`

From the package menu select Lock version:

And that is all, the version currently installed at the time of the lock will stay installed even during upgrades.

That's all folks!

Answer (score 0):

rdesktop is still available and if I recall right, that's what tsclient depends on.
(sudo apt-get install rdesktop)

And yes, remmina is not good at rdp atm.

Answer (score 0):

I know how you feel. My key bindings are all over the place with remmmina and I keep on getting unity popping up now and again. I've reverted to tsclient ...

Download tsclient from http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/tsclient and installed the usual way. The missing libpanel-applet2-0 dependency is not really needed so the force all option worked for me.

For 64-bit arch:

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -i tsclient_0.150-4ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

For 32-bit system:

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -i tsclient_0.150-4ubuntu2_i386.deb
```

Comment: Your answer is nearly identical to @jokerdino's answer.